# Is there a list of all available Android Gradle variables?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-studio-2.3

Is there a list somewhere of all the available Gradle variables at my disposal in Android Studio? For example, how are you supposed to know that 'archiveBaseName' exists?

Comment: https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you. Didn't know about this.

Comment: That link is interesting, but doesn't really provide what I was asking for.  For example, 'archiveBaseName' doesn't occur on that page nor on any of the many links I tried from that page.  it may be buried deep in some obscure offshoot of the page, but that doesn't constitute a reference.